# Cannot take picture or choose image from gallery in IOS

Tags: ionic3

When I am fetching an image from the gallery, I get an error on SELECT_PICTURE or take a photo from the camera.

My Code is :

-- For Photo Gallery

```ts
const Liboptions: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM       
}

this.camera.getPicture(Liboptions).then((imagePath) => {});
```

-- For Camera

```ts
const CamOptions: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA  
}

this.camera.getPicture(CamOptions).then((imagePath)=>{})
```

Show error is:

```
TypeError: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"])(this, "getPicture", { "callbackOrder": "reverse" }, arguments)', 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"])' is an instance of Object)
```

Comment: can you include your package.json content in your post? Which version of ionic-native and camera are you using?

Comment: No, Do not included package.json in my post.
ionic native version 2.9.0 and camera version 4.0.3